# Keyword is tokenized and exact match does not work

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field named id, that looks like that:

`ventures.something.123`

It's mapping:

```
{  
   "id":{  
      "fields":{  
         "keyword":{  
            "ignore_above":256,
            "type":"keyword"
         }
      },
      "type":"text"
   }
}
```

My understanding is that a keyword only allows for EXACT matching - which is what I want.

However, the analyzer tells me it's tokenized:

`> http http://localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze field=id text='ventures.house.1137'`

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "end_offset": 14,
            "position": 0,
            "start_offset": 0,
            "token": "ventures.house",
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>"
        },
        {
            "end_offset": 19,
            "position": 1,
            "start_offset": 15,
            "token": "1137",
            "type": "<NUM>"
        }
    ]
}
```

... and a search for an id returns indeed ALL ids that start with `ventures.house`.

Why is that and how can I come to the EXACT matching?

It's ES 5.2.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2

not_analyzed:
    Index this field, so it is searchable, but index the value exactly as specified. Do not analyze it.

```
{
  "tag": {
      "type":     "string",
      "index":    "not_analyzed"
  }
}
```

Comment: That information is for ES 1.x and 2.x, not for 5.x. `not_analyzed` has been replaced by `keyword`.

Answer (score 0):

I misread the mapping, it looks like my `elasticsearch-dsl` library does not create a keyword directly, but adds it as a subfield.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining the field 'id' as keyword ?

In this case it does not get analyzed but stored as is.
When I understand your question correctly this is what you want.

```
{  
 "id":{
   "type":"keyword"
 }
}
```

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html

I hope this helped. Christian